# Alterar posição do elemento com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Atualmente, o elemento está assim :

```
<li>
  <a>
    <i> </i>
  </a>
</li>
```

Mas, eu quero trocar a posição da tag **i** com JavaScript, para fora da tag **a**, tornando as tags irmãs, ou seja :

```
<li>
  <a> </a>
  <i> </i>
</li>
```

Ja tentei fazer isso com insertAdjacentHTML, mas algo está dando errado, pois eu quero tirar o elemento do pai, e por isso não estou conseguindo

Comment: Se entendi certo, basta pegar o elemento `a` e fazer um `li.appendChild(a)`. O elemento `i` será movido para o final da `li`.

Comment: Obrigada!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicionei um id na li, pra ficar mais fácil o exemplo:

HTML:

```
<li id="li">
  <a>
    <i>a</i>
  </a>
</li>
```

JS:

```
//Salva os nodes em variaveis
var li = document.getElementById("li"); 
var a = li.firstElementChild;
var i = a.firstElementChild;

li.prepend(i); //adiciona o <i> na li
a.removeChild(i);// remove o <i> do <a>
```

Fiddle do exemplo. https://jsfiddle.net/xLyunqw4/